# Getting endNodes from a list of matched nodes

Tags: neo4j

Starting with Neo4j, I am pretty sure, this question could be even stupid because the solution might be so easy. But I am not sure how to solve this, I want to combine two queries:

First I search for nodes, which are all themselves parent nodes:

`MATCH (parentnodes:DemoMenue) WHERE (parentnodes)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]-> () RETURN parentnodes`

Then I want do get the endNodes for each of the matched parentnodes above. If just doing it with one specified parentnode it would for example work like this:

`MATCH (x:DemoMenue {title: "A2"})-[r]-() RETURN endNode(r)`

Now what is the suggested way/technique in Cypher to apply my second query to each of the matching parentnodes of my first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two queries can be merged into one without using a foreach loop:

```
MATCH (parentnodes:DemoMenue)-[r:IS_PARENT_OF]-> () RETURN endNode(r)
```

If you want to do something for each result in a collection, you can use [Foreach](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-foreach.html), but keep in mind that you can only use `SET` in foreach, not `return`.

And to complete my answer, your query is not 'returning' any collection, so you can't use foreach on it, you'll have to use `collect` before

Comment: thanks for your quick response :) Hm, so your combined query would return the endNode/s from the two childs of my root node, but not for the remainng deeper nested parent nodes.

Going to check if I can accomplish my goal with a collection and foreach now.

Comment: Can you provide a dataset to try out this query? It's strange that it doesn only return two nodes, it should get every node related to a parent node with `:IS_PARENT_OF` relation

Comment: Oh, guess I described that wrongly. The result of your query actually returns all nodes, but just two branches from the direct childs of the root node. But in my DemoMenue structure I have not just these two parentnodes but 6 (including root) and I want to generate a branch with child nodes for each of them.

The dataset looks like:

Comment: Now that was not nicely formatted :( But the titles are actually describing the  structure:

root -> A, B...

A -> A1, A2

...and so on

Comment: You should look at Path system in cypher. I recommend you to edit your question, add a Dataset (with relations) and explain what you need. Because here the base problem is solved, what you need now is to find out how to get child nodes using a depth parameter. I edited answer to match it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code, all that code should not be in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use:

```
MATCH (parentnodes:DemoMenue)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]-> (endNode)
RETURN endNodes
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for your response. Yes, that works. I were wrong in how I stated my question. Somehow I mixed up endNode with a concept of "branches".

Redefining, this is what I want to accomplish:

1.) Select all Nodes, works with what we have: ```MATCH (parentnodes:DemoMenue)-[:IS_PARENT_OF]->```

2.) For EACH of these parent nodes return a SEPARATE structure that represents the parent node with its direct children of path length 1.

Say I have 6 parent nodes in total, would it be possible to get them back, all separated (not connected), with just their children of path length 1?